# Django: How to retrieve all attributes from related models for GeoJSON serialization?

Tags: django, postgis, geojson

I have two Models `Site` and `Cell`, every site has multiple Cells.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import PointField

class SiteManager(models.Model):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name, state_code, location):
         return self.get(name=name, state_code=state_code, location=location)

class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    state_code = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    location = PointField()

    objects = SiteManager()

    class Meta:
         unique_together = [['name', 'state_code', 'location']]

    def natural_key(self):
         return (self.name, self.state_code, self.location)

class Cell(models.Model):
    tech = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    azimuth = models.IntegerField()
    sector_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    frequency_band = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    power = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def natural_key(self):
         return (self.tech, self.azimuth,) + self.site.natural_key()
    natural_key.dependencies = ['astmaps.site']
```

I want to retrieve the complete `Cell` attributes with the related attributes in the `Site` model, for me to `Serialize` the resultant `Cell`'s, into `GeoJson` data, I can easily `Serialize` the `Site` model like:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize # GeoJSON Serializer

sites = Site.objects.all()
sitesData = serialize('geojson', sites, geometry_field='location',
    fields=('name', 'state_code'))
```

which gives me a `GeoJson` `featureCollection` object like:

```
{
            "type":"FeatureCollection",
            "crs":{
            "type":"name",
            "properties":{
                "name":"EPSG:4326"
             }
        },
        "features":[
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name":"02101",
                "state_code":2
             },
             "geometry":{
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[
                   1.34944,
                   36.1586
                ]
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

But when It comes to the `Cell` model, I can't successfully get the geometry field from the related model always `null`.
Since the `Cell` model has the `Site` model as a related model, I've used the function `select_related()` to get the related attributes:

```
cells = Cell.objects.select_related('site').all()
cellsData = serialize('geojson', cells, geometry_field='site_location', 
    fields=('azimuth', ...))
```

But the `GeoJson` `Serialize` function could not identify the `Site` model attributes from the `cells` `QuerySet`:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "crs":{
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{
         "name":"EPSG:4326"
      }
   },
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "azimuth":340
         },
         "geometry":null
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "azimuth":340
         },
         "geometry":null
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "azimuth":240
         },
         "geometry":null
      }
   ]
}
```

I've tested the query returned by Django ORM equivalent directly on the database:

```
    cells = Cell.objects.select_related('site').all()
    >>> print(cells.query)
SELECT "app_cell"."id", "app_cell"."tech", "app_cell"."azimuth", "app_cell"."sector_id", "app_cell"."frequency_band", "app_cell"."power", "app_cell"."site_id", "app_cell"."id", "app_site"."name", "app_site"."state_code", "app_site"."location"::bytea FROM "app_cell" INNER JOIN "app_site" ON ("app_cell"."site_id" = "app_site"."id")
```

Which gives me a correct results (all the attributes or columns of the two models):
[image]

I've also used `Natural Keys`, which is the serialization strategy for foreign keys and other relations (as I've read in the documentation and changed the models accordingly):

```
cellsData = serialize('geojson', cells, geometry_field='site_location', 
    fields=('azimuth', ...), use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

But the same result, the Serialize method couldn't identify the `Site` model attributes.

How can I get all the attributes of multiple related models to get serialized using the `GeoJSON Serializer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get what I want by using raw `sql` query plus the `json_build_object`  and [`ST_AsGeoJSON`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) of `PostGIS` extention:

```
from django.db import connection
def sites_list(request):

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""select json_build_object(
    'type', 'FeatureCollection',
    'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json)
    )
    from ( SELECT "app_cell"."id", "app_cell"."tech", "app_cell"."azimuth", "app_cell"."sector_id", 
                        "app_cell"."frequency_band", "app_cell"."power", "app_cell"."site_id", "app_site"."name" 
                        AS "site_name", "app_site"."state_code", "app_cell"."location"::bytea::geometry AS "site_location" 
                        FROM "app_cell" INNER JOIN "app_site" ON ("app_cell"."site_id" = "app_site"."id")
        ) as t(id, tech, azimuth, sector_id, frequency_band, power, site_id, site_name, state_code, geom);""")
geojson = cursor.fetchone()

return JsonResponse(geojson[0], safe=False)
```

I had some problems in the `JavaScript` side, when using:

```
cursor.fetchall()
return JsonResponse(geojson, safe=False)
```

the returned `GeoJSON` object was surrounded by [[]] double brackets, because `cursor.fetchall()` return a `tuple`, So, I've used the `cursor.fetchone()` to get the geoJSON object surrunded only by single brackets [], and used the  the index 0 to of the resulted tuble to get the only tuple content as a string, and finally the `JsonResponse` function will return that result as a `JSON` object.